# How can one replace one specific URL of a rich text cell with a different URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with various rich text cells that contain different formatting, mainly bold and hyperlinked text. I've found that some of these cells have URLs that are invalid, and so I'd like to update them whilst maintaining the position in the spreadsheet as well as their rich text formatting.

My current approach somewhat works, but I find that it either indexes out of bounds or the resulting formatting will not be the same as the original input, hence my hope of asking here for anyone who might know more about why this is happening.

So far I've tried the following:

```
function iterateCells() {
  var badLink = 'https://google.com'
  var goodLink = 'https://a.co'

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("A8:A10")
  var numRows = sheetRange.getNumRows()
  var numCols = sheetRange.getNumColumns()

  // For each cell
  for (var i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numRows; j++) {
      Logger.log('i' + i)
      Logger.log('j' + j)
      // Get the current cell and its text.
      var cell = sheetRange.getCell(j, i)
      var fullCellText = cell.getValue()
      var currentRichTextCellValues = cell.getRichTextValue().getRuns();

      // Establish new rich text to override the existing content.
      var newRichText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(fullCellText)

      // For each piece of rich text in the given cell.
      for (var k = 0; k < currentRichTextCellValues.length; k++) {
        currentRunText = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getText()
        firstOffset = fullCellText.indexOf(currentRunText)

        // Build the new rich text with text set to be that of the existing cell with whatever formatting the existing portion of the cell has.
        newRichText.setTextStyle(firstOffset, firstOffset + currentRunText.length, currentRichTextCellValues[k].getTextStyle())

        // Check if there exists a URL.
        // If so, if the URL needs to be replaced (a "bad" URL), replace it with the "good" URL. Otherwise, just set the URL to be the existing URL.          
        potentialUrl = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getLinkUrl()
        if (potentialUrl) {
          if (potentialUrl === badLink) {
            newRichText.setLinkUrl(firstOffset, firstOffset + currentRunText.length, goodLink)
          } else {
            newRichText.setLinkUrl(firstOffset, firstOffset + currentRunText.length, potentialUrl)
          }
        }
      }

      // Once done, overwrite the cell contents.
      sheet.getRange(cell.getA1Notation()).setRichTextValue(newRichText.build())
    }
  }
}
```

This function does not error out, but what's odd is that the formatting is off. See the "before" and "after" below:

**Before**:

[Before image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZCsY.png)

**After**:

[After image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyses.png)

Notice how the "bad link" text of the third cell has a new space, and the ending "another good" text has a space before it that has the same styling.

Is it possible to get some insight into what's causing this weird formatting? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, in order to retrieve the first index, `firstOffset = fullCellText.indexOf(currentRunText)` is used. In this case, when the text of `currentRunText` is included in `fullCellText` multiple times, the correct position cannot be returned. I'm worried that this might be related to your current issue.
- In your script, `getCell`, `getValue`, `getRichTextValue`, `setRichTextValue` are used in the loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function iterateCells() {
  var badLink = 'https://google.com/';
  var goodLink = 'https://a.co/';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("A8:A10");

  // I modified the below script.
  var richTextValues = sheetRange.getRichTextValues();
  var updatedRichTextValues = richTextValues.map(r => r.map(c => {
    var newRichText = c.copy();
    c.getRuns().forEach(e => {
      var link = e.getLinkUrl();
      if (link && link == badLink) { // or if (link && link.includes(badLink)) {
        newRichText.setLinkUrl(e.getStartIndex(), e.getStartIndex() + e.getText().length, goodLink);
      }
    });
    return newRichText.build();
  }));
  sheetRange.setRichTextValues(updatedRichTextValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, all hyperlinks `badLink` of cells "A8:A10" is replaced with `goodLink`.
- If the link is not replaced, please modify `link == badLink` to `link.includes(badLink)` and test it again.

#### Note:

- As additional information, if you want to achieve your goal by directly modifying your showing script, please modify your showing script as follows. By this modification, the correct first index can be used in your script.

  - From

    ```
      firstOffset = fullCellText.indexOf(currentRunText)
    ```
  - To

    ```
      firstOffset = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getStartIndex();
    ```

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: Wow, wow, wow! You perfectly fixed this for me! You brought up such a good point, that if the same text appears more than once, the code will break, which perfectly explains why sometimes it worked and other times it didn't! I love your approach as well, it's so much cleaner and is much more efficient! Thank you, so, so, SO much for your help, I am beyond grateful for taking the time to help!